# Does what function space does nth derivative differential equation belong to?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces

From second order linear differential equation, two linearly independent equations can be found. Superposing the equations spans a plane of functions that serves as a the answer to the differential equation.

From this it led me to assume that then, the original differential equation must have belonged to a function space spanned by at least up to the 3rd derivative. Like how Hilbert space is a vector space analog to functions, span of two linearly independent answers among many other possibilities that do not satisfy the DE, would have to exist in space of higher order.

So, is this line of thinking correct? And if so, is there a limit up to which nth space the span of linearly independent functions can belong?

Comment: Yes, the solutions to a linear homogeneous DE of order 2 span a 2-dimensional plane in $C^2$. It is not clear where you get the 3rd derivative from. $n$th order linear homogeneous DE span an $n$ dimensional subspace in $C^n$, there is no limit on $n$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If, ^n, is a function space spanned  by n dimensions, each orthogonal axis must be list of functions, like how list of numbers are ascribed to each axis. Then, in what hierarchy if there is one, are such list of function ordered?

Comment: No, $C^n$ is the space of $n$ times continuously differentiable functions, it is an infinite-dimensional Banach space with a suitable norm. The domain has to be chosen to be a closed interval over which the coefficients of the DE are continuous.

Comment: Then do the solution to second order non-homogeneous ODE which belongs to an affine plane belong to a normed vector space also? It does seems to fit the definition you have posted above, but it also seem to not include the zero vector.

Comment: Yes, these solutions are also elements of the corresponding $C^n([a,b])$ and form an affine $n$-dimensional subspace in this infinite dimensional space.